# htaccess rewrite URL if domain doesn't equal and subfolder is this

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get a rewrite working and need a hand...

I've got a set of websites, which domains are like this

```
example.com
example.co.uk
example.ie
example.com/gm
```

The way the site is setup means that all domains can display the .com/gm content (GM doesn't have it's own domain and we want it only served from the .com domain)

So I'm trying to redirect anyone using incorrect URLs to the correct TLD with the **gm** subfolder.  E.G:

```
going to www.example.co.uk/gm would 301 to www.example.com/gm
```

I've currently got this:

```
RewriteCond %!{HTTP_HOST}:{REQUEST_URI} !^example.com:gm$ [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/gm$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which obviously isn't happy

Appreciate a point in the right direction, basically from what I can tell I need a rule that checks the domain doesn't equal .com if they're trying to get to /gm/ and redirects them to .com/gm/

Thanks!!

Comment: That code is *way* off. Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to check if the `/gm/` path was requested in the RewriteRule, and prefix that with a RewriteCond that checks for the host name – something like this should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(gm/.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me out however this doesn't seem to redirect anything :( sorry I'm not really good with htaccess stuff d I'm not sure what the issue could be - if this is meant to work

Comment: That’s not that easy to debug from the outside. We don’t know what else you might have in your .htaccess, etc. You could enable rewrite logging to get a more detailed view of what is going on internally.

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess is full of syntax errors.

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gm/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect

- example.co.uk/gm

to

- example.com/gm

Clear your browser's cache before testing this.

Comment: :( I dunno what is going on but that doesn't seem to redirect anything :( even if I put it first in the htaccess (before any other rewrites)

Comment: The redirect works fine on my system. Looks like mod_rewrite isnt enabled.

Comment: It is, there's quite a few other redirects and rewrites in the htaccess :(